# hexadecimal value

Tags: hex

```
return jjMoveStringLiteralDfa1_0(0x140L, 0x4000000000000L);
```

i try to convert `0x4000000000000L` hexa to binary and text but i get strange characters. Is this hexadecimal value?

Comment: What language are you using? You should add a tag for your language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0x4000000000000` is a hex number, the L at the end is telling you that it's a `long` integer (in this case, I'm guessing an 8 byte int).

Answer (score 1):

The `0x` prefix is standard to several languages. It denotes the start of a hexadecimal number. The `L` suffix denotes a long value in several languages (e.g. C).

If you regroup it it's easier to see its value:

```
   4 0000 0000 0000
```

which is equivalent to:

```
0004 0000 0000 0000
```

Each group is two bytes, so the total length is eight bytes.

The two most significant bytes (the ones on the left) are `00` and `04` which is `0000 0000 0000 0100` in binary. In other words, the value has only the 51st bit set (it's counted from the right, the so called least-significant bit), all other bits are cleared. Looks like a bit mask (a flag). For completeness, here's the binary representation:

```
0000 0000 0000 0100  0000 0000 0000 0000  0000 0000 0000 0000  0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Each space delimited group is a nibble (a half-byte), each four groups equal two bytes.

So the number is a perfectly legal 64bit value. But maybe you confuse the value with representing a character ? Because it certainly doesn't, it's waaaay outside the Unicode range (which goes up to 0x10FFF IIRC).

BTW, the number converted to decimal is 1.125.899.906.842.620, all of which a decent calculator should be able to show you (the Apple calculator in Mac OS X does a good job when set to programmer mode, for example).